# WebApi OData per user security on property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have some entities which have data that must only be accessible for some users.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual Bar { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

For example `Bar.Secret` must only be accessible by `UserA` but not by `UserB`.
I could so something like this:

```
public class BarsController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        if (User.Identity.Name != "UserA") 
            return Unauthorized();

        return _db.Bars();
    }
}
```

Besides that being a bad implementation. It doesn't cover this controller:

```
public class FoosController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return _db.Foos();
    }
}
```

Which could be called with `/odata/Foos?$expand=Bars` and then I could view `Bar.Secret`. I can't just disable `$expand` on `Foo` because that query is totally legit for `UserA` and also needed.

Is there a way to make OData validate the queries against some predicate that involves the requested entities.

Something like

```
public class SecureEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public bool ValidateResult(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        return entities.All(x => x.Secret == UserA.Secret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the query options *before* the query is executed and fail if the user is not authorized to retrieve the requested data. To do this, derive from `EnableQueryAttribute` and override `ValidateQuery`.

```
public class SecureEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public virtual void ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        base.ValidateQuery(request, queryOptions);

        // Insert custom logic, possibly looking at queryOptions.SelectExpand
        // or queryOptions.RawValues.
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the above answer, how can an additional condition be added to the query? Providing a code example will be highly appreciated!
E.G where (x => x.Secret == UserA.Secret);